# Homebrew installed Maven is not working

Tags: maven, maven-3, homebrew

I am using a MacBook. I use homebrew installed maven 3.1.1:

```
brew install homebrew/versions/maven31
```

Installation is successful. I can see it is installed in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven31/3.1.1
```

Under the above path, if I run ls , I see the following files:

```
INSTALL_RECEIPT.json    LICENSE         NOTICE          README.txt      bin         libexec
```

I then edited my .bash_profile, added the following path:

```
# MAVEN
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/maven31/3.1.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
```

After that, I think my maven should be ready to work. I opened a new terminal, run command `mvn --version` , but I got the following output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
```

Why maven is not working? how to get rid of the problem?

(Please don't suggest me to download maven binary from their website, I want to know how to make it work with homebrew installation.)

**===UPDATE===**

command `echo $PATH` shows me:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/maven31/3.1.1/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin ...etc
```

Comment: Only the people who made the homebrew package can explain how they busted it. Maybe instead you should ask for help in making your code work with the standard distribution?

Comment: Setting M2_HOME is almost never needed. Try not setting it.

Comment: Best is download from official source here: http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi? and use it...

Comment: @bmargulies , not setting M2_HOME is the trick. Could you please make an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `M2_HOME` is hardly ever a good idea, and the homebrew install may not be shaped right. Don't set it.